# How to access object from session in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to access a object using session scope . I am doing this in jsp

```
 ${sessionScope.loginBean.loginName}
```

but its returning empty value. Is this the correct way of accessing session variable in java class I have already set loginBean inside the session.

```
 session.setAttribute("loginBean",loginBean)
```

please help. thanks

Comment: Is it accessible as simply `loginBean.loginName`? Does other JSP EL evaluate correctly (i.e., is your container configured correctly)?

Comment: Hi Dave, Yes I can access simple variables like ${sessionScope.name} on the same page.

Comment: Sorry Dave, I didn't get you earlier, Actually no, I can't access it simply loginBean.loginName. But I can access it in my java class. if I do LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean) session.getAttribute("loginBean");Still don't know what is the problem with above code.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it, which means it's either not in session yet, or something else.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I found I was using the wrong name... ahhhhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the Jsp in Debug mode and see whether the value of the loginBean is set properly.

Comment: If I do the sysout in my java file its returning the values.. I did LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean) session.getAttribute("loginBean"); then I did sysout(loginBean.loginName). Its returning me values

Comment: @user965884 I may be wrong but just a guess. Is the Jsp getting executed before the java class is being called?

Comment: No Sriram, I can access other variable from the class even I can access this bean if I put it in a model.attribute inside my controller but I want to check why SessionScope is not working.